# invalid linker name in argument '-fuse-ld=lld'?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to build a project that uses lld and I get the following error:

```
invalid linker name in argument '-fuse-ld=lld'
```

I have already installed llvm with "brew install llvm" it is still not working.

Answer (score 4):

`brew install llvm` should work, but you need to use `brew info llvm` to check the default install path first (it usually is `/usr/local/opt/llvm`).

So, if you need to have `llvm` first in your `PATH`, run:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Then all the build works.

Comment: Apple Silicon: `export PATH="$(brew --prefix)/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"`

Answer (score 0):

`brew info llvm` 
to get this

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/include"
```